# svn - command line - Is there a script or command that will commit every changes?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, svn, tortoise-svn

By "every change" I mean TortoiseSVN's "Commit" button.
It removes the deleted files, adds new ones, and commit the changes.
At least these are the ones I know of, but there may be others as well.
(I just press "All" and push Commit in Tortoise.)

RabbitVCS is available for Linux, but the cli version's `commit` == `svn commit`.
Is there a small script or something that could imitate Tortoise's commit?

**Environment is Linux with bash prompt. (SVN 1.7.5)**

Comment: RabbitVCS seems to work now, but I'm still interested in a shell script that would do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the root of your working directory.

`svn add . --force`

(This recursively traverses your working directory and does an `svn add` on every file it finds that is not already under version control.)

Next do this:

`svn rm $( svn status | sed -e '/^!/!d' -e 's/^!//' )`

(This runs `svn status`.  The status command recursively gives a list of everything that has changed in the working directory.  The weird `sed` command finds all the lines starting with "!" (which is how svn status indicates a deleted file.))

Now do:

`svn commit`

Not that I really advise doing this.  It would be preferable to just use "svn rm oldfile" instead of "rm oldfile" as you are doing your modifications.  The "svn add . --force" isn't so great either: it's going to check in all the temporary files and object files that you generate while testing.  It would be better to just "svn add newfile" when you care about adding a new file.

I typically run "svn status -u" before every checkin to get a clear picture of what has changed in my working copy.

I found the answer for the svn rm part at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265122/how-can-i-programmatically-detect-missing-files-in-tar-archive-and-delete-them-f?rq=1, which in turn credits http://geryit.com/blog/command-line-subversion-practices/.

Comment: Thank you! Well, Tortoise and Rabbit basically commit every change (updates, new files, deletions) if you choose to do so. For continuous backup, I use Dropbox. But having SVN is good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I Use & Schedule This Batch Script . It Working Well.

```
CD "MyPath"

for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %%i in (`svn status ^| findstr /R "^\!"`) do (svn del "%%i %%j")

svn add * --depth=infinity --force 

svn commit . -m "My Message"
```

Comment: The question is tagged Linux but this answer applies to Windows.